# Wijmo5 flexgrid with Angular8 - Changing Datamap selection reverts changed text in edited text column

Tags: angular, wijmo, wijmo5, wijmo-grid

I am using wijmo 5 flexgrid with Angular 8 and trying to create an inline editable grid with Edit button at every row. Each row has a datamap column and a text column both of which should be editable when the Edit button of that specific row is clicked. 
After clicking Edit button, first the text field (Employee Name) is edited. After that, when I change selection of the datamap dropdown (Department), the changed text in the text field reverts to the original text. How to keep the changed text in Employee Name text field after selection change in Department datamap field? The Code is in the link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g9wk57?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { CollectionView, ObservableArray } from 'wijmo/wijmo';
import * as wjCore from 'wijmo/wijmo';
import * as wjInput from 'wijmo/wijmo.input';
import * as wjGrid from 'wijmo/wijmo.grid';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private _currentEditItem: any = null;

  public data : any;
  public deptList: any = [
    {'deptId':'D1', 'deptName':'Accounts'},
    {'deptId':'D2', 'deptName':'Development'},
    {'deptId':'D3', 'deptName':'HR'}
    ];

    public empList: any = [
      {'empId':'E1', 'empName':'AA', 'deptId':'D3'},
      {'empId':'E2', 'empName':'BB', 'deptId':'D2'},
      {'empId':'E3', 'empName':'CC', 'deptId':'D1'},
      {'empId':'E4', 'empName':'DD', 'deptId':'D2'}
    ];

  @ViewChild('flex') flex:wjGrid.FlexGrid;

public deptMap = new wjGrid.DataMap(this.deptList, 'deptId', 'deptName');
    constructor() {
      this.data = new wjCore.CollectionView(this.empList);
  }  

initializeGrid(flex: wjGrid.FlexGrid) {
    flex.rows.defaultSize = 40;
    // custom formatter to paint buttons and editors
    flex.formatItem.addHandler((s: wjGrid.FlexGrid, e: wjGrid.FormatItemEventArgs) => {
      if (e.panel == s.cells) {
        let col = s.columns[e.col],
          item = s.rows[e.row].dataItem;
        if (item == this._currentEditItem) {
          // create editors and buttons for the item being edited
          switch (col.binding) {
            case 'buttons':
              e.cell.innerHTML = document.getElementById('tplBtnEditMode').innerHTML;
              e.cell['dataItem'] = item;
              break;            
            case 'empName':
              e.cell.innerHTML = '<input class="form-control" ' +
                'id="' + col.binding + '" ' +
                'value="' + s.getCellData(e.row, e.col, true) + '"/>';
              break;
          }
        } else {
          // create buttons for items not being edited
          switch (col.binding) {
            case 'buttons':
              e.cell.innerHTML = document.getElementById('tplBtnViewMode').innerHTML;
              e.cell['dataItem'] = item;
              break;
          }
        }
      }
    });

    // handle button clicks
    flex.addEventListener(flex.hostElement, 'click', (e: MouseEvent) => {
      let targetBtn: HTMLButtonElement;
      if (e.target instanceof HTMLButtonElement) {
        targetBtn = e.target;
      }
      // else if (e.target instanceof HTMLSpanElement && e.target.classList.contains('glyphicon')) {
      //   targetBtn = e.target.parentElement as HTMLButtonElement;
      // }
      if (targetBtn) {
        // get button's data item
        let item = wjCore.closest(targetBtn, '.wj-cell')['dataItem'];
        // handle buttons
        switch (targetBtn.id) {
          // start editing this item
          case 'btnEdit':
            this._editItem(item);
            break;
          // remove this item from the collection
          // case 'btnDelete':
          //   (<wjCore.CollectionView>flex.collectionView).remove(item);
          //   break;
          // commit edits
          case 'btnOK':
            this._commitEdit();
            break;
          // cancel edits
          case 'btnCancel':
            this._cancelEdit();
            break;
        }
      }
      e.preventDefault();
    });

    // exit edit mode when scrolling the grid or losing focus
    flex.scrollPositionChanged.addHandler(this._cancelEdit.bind(this));
    flex.lostFocus.addHandler(this._cancelEdit.bind(this));
  }

  private _editItem(item: any) {
    this._cancelEdit();
    this._currentEditItem = item;
    this.flex.invalidate();
  }

  private _commitEdit() {
    if (this._currentEditItem) {
      this.flex.columns.forEach((col: any) => {
        let input = <HTMLInputElement>this.flex.hostElement.querySelector('#' + col.binding);
        if (input) {
          let value = wjCore.changeType(input.value, col.dataType, col.format);
          if (wjCore.getType(value) == col.dataType) {
            this._currentEditItem[col.binding] = value;
          }
        }
      });
    }

    console.log(this._currentEditItem);
    this._currentEditItem = null;
    this.flex.invalidate();
  }

  private _cancelEdit() {
    if (this._currentEditItem) {
      this._currentEditItem = null;
      this.flex.invalidate();
    }
  }

}
```

***app.component.html***

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>
            DataMap
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- content -->
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <wj-flex-grid #flex [itemsSource]="data"
            [headersVisibility]="'Column'" (initialized)="initializeGrid(flex)">
            <wj-flex-grid-column [header]="'Employee Name'" [binding]="'empName'" [width]="'4*'">
            </wj-flex-grid-column>
            <wj-flex-grid-column [header]="'Department'" [binding]="'deptId'" [width]="'4*'" [dataMap]="deptMap">
            </wj-flex-grid-column>
            <wj-flex-grid-column [header]="'Actions'" [binding]="'buttons'" [width]="'3*'"></wj-flex-grid-column>
        </wj-flex-grid>

        <!-- template for buttons on items in view mode -->
        <div id="tplBtnViewMode" style="display:none">
            <button id="btnEdit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
        Edit
    </button>
        </div>

        <!-- template for buttons on items in edit mode -->
        <div id="tplBtnEditMode" style="display:none">
            <button id="btnOK" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
        OK
    </button>
            <button id="btnCancel" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">
        Cancel
    </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used ComboBox instead of DataMap to edit the values
[wijmo forum](https://www.grapecity.com/forums/wijmo/wijmo5-flexgrid-with-angul#hi-madhuthe-reason-that-th)

Sample :
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g9wk57?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)